# Purpose of Texture Unbinding?

Tags: cuda, textures

What is the purpose of unbinding a CUDA texture bound to linear memory or CUDA Array?

In many of my CUDA programs, I use textures bound to pitch linear memory using `cudaBindTexture2D`. At the end of the function, I use `cudaUnbindTexture` to release the texture.

A few times it happened that I forgot to unbind the texture. But it had no apparent affect on the performance and results of the function.

Is it really necessary to unbind the texture? What are the possible consequences if I don't unbind it?
Will it cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each architecture has a limit to how many textures can be bound at the same time. The number is listed as `Maximum number of textures that can be bound to a kernel` in the CUDA C Programming Guide. It is 128 for CC < 3 and 256 for CC >= 3. If you don't unbind your textures, your program won't be able to handle more than that number of textures.

Comment: It means if I continuously call the function without unbinding the texture, eventually, the limit of 128 will exhaust and the program will fail?

Comment: I don't know if repeatedly binding the same texture takes up additional slots. If you find out if that is or is not the case, please add an answer to let us know.

Answer (score -3):

In Blender Cycles, reach the limit will output images like this:

http://www.xuanran001.com/public/repository/a69f/2083/c9be/4738/b36a/a138/49d5/3c54/preview/image.jpg

Code is here (`intern/cycles/render/image.cpp`)

```
if(slot == images.size()) {
  /* max images limit reached */
  if(images.size() == tex_num_images) {
    printf("ImageManager::add_image: byte image limit reached %d, skipping '%s'\n",
           tex_num_images, filename.c_str());
    return -1;
  }

  images.resize(images.size() + 1);
}
```

more reading: http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?309902-Suggestion-for-workaround-for-cycles-texture-limit